# Postgres copy with date range

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple PSQL query that I run to grab some certs that I have stored in my DB and copy them to a tmp folder. All works well, however, I've been tasked to do this monthly instead of just grabbing everything. So, I want to pass a date range but from what I can see from the copy syntax this doesn't seem to be possible. Any help would be appreciated. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
/usr/bin/psql dbname dbuser -c "copy certs (x509) to '/tmp/certs'"
```

Comment: Would a view work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query with copy.  Something like this should work:

```
COPY (SELECT * from certs where your_date > '2019-01-01T00:00:00') TO '/tmp/certs';
```